# Show text and image on hover in search results

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to show an image and a text on hover when I fetch the search results in my sample website

I have tried using the css hover property where I added the related the class inside the hover in scss file.

```
 <div class="search-results" *ngFor="let user of extResults">
    <div>{{ user.user }}</div>
    <div class="ext">
      <span class="icon-phone icon-font-icon_Phone"></span>{{ user.ext }}
      <a [href]="'mailto:' + user.email" class="anchor"
        ><span class="icon-email icon-font-icon_Mail name"></span>
        <span class="email-text">Email</span></a
      >
    </div>
  </div>

.search-results {
  color: #424242;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;

  &:hover {
    background-color: rgba(#d8d8d8, 0.26);
  }
  .ext {
    color: #979797;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: colfax-medium;
  }
  .icon-phone {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    &:before {
      color: #d9415c;
    }
  }
  .anchor {
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .icon-email {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    &:before {
      color: #d9415c;
    }
  }
  .email-text {
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #d9415c;
  }
}
```

Expected to see the text "Email" and the "icon-font-icon_Mail" on hover of the results but actual output is that I am seeing the "Email" and "Icon" in all of the search-results.

[image: Expected][image: Actual]

Comment: your question is not clear. if you want to change class on hover just add you class in   hover e.g. .normalClass {background-color: #fff;} .nomralClass:hover {background-color: #000;}

Comment: No I want to add a text "Email" and an "Icon" on hover as shown in the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding mouse enter and leave event listeners as:

**HTML Code**

```
   <div class="search-results" *ngFor="let user of extResults;let i = index;">
   <div (mouseenter)="mouseHovering(i)" (mouseleave)="mouseLeft(i)">
     <div>{{ user.user }}</div>
     <div class="ext">
        <span class="icon-phone icon-font-icon_Phone"></span>{{ user.ext }}
         <div *ngIf="user.isHovering">
         <a [href]="'mailto:' + user.email" class="anchor"
         ><span class="icon-email icon-font-icon_Mail name"></span>
         <span class="email-text">Email</span></a>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**TS Code**

```
extResults;
isHovering = false;

 mouseHovering(index:any) {
   this.extResults[index].isHovering = true; 
 }
 mouseLeft(index:any) {
     this.extResults[index].isHovering = false;
 }
```

Hope this will help

Comment: on hover on a single element all the elements are showing the "Email" and "Icon"

Comment: Then add another div after ngFor div and add the event to newly added div. I have edited my answer check once

Comment: Can you able to add this on stackblitz? will solve this

Comment: check this issue solved : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k5gbtn?embed=1  also edited my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot.. really appreciate your effort

Answer (score 1):

If you can add a property (for now let's call it `isHovered`) to each element in your `extResults` it's fairly easy.

```
<div class="search-results" *ngFor="let user of extResults" (mouseenter)="user.isHovered = true" (mouseleave)="user.isHovered = false">
  <div>{{ user.user }}</div>
  <div class="ext">
    <span class="icon-phone icon-font-icon_Phone"></span>{{ user.ext }}
    <a *ngIf="user.isHovered" [href]="'mailto:' + user.email" class="anchor">
      <span class="icon-email icon-font-icon_Mail name"></span>
      <span class="email-text">Email</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

By adding it to each element you ensure that only this element will have its state changed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use angular directives like `ng-mouseover` and `ng-show`.

Here's an example of the desired behavior [link](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/eGohFqiGKmkonmLwT3g1?p=preview&preview)

Comment: Can you help me do the same in Angular 4

Comment: For Angular 2+ you can use on-mouseover instead. You have to have both on-mouseover and on-mouseleave for it to work.